# Using as table after output when merging table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a question when I used 'as table' to inserting data from Ouput of Merge table. Does SQL Server create a temp table with name is ValuesInsertToMbGpCommSettingLog and then we can retrieve data from it?
You can see more detail in image below.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, that's why you are persisting the output through an insert into a physical table.

Comment: Because I used temp table before, then I used this way to avoid using temp table that causes low performance. That's the reason why I have to make sure it will not create a temp table again.